# Can dead locks be prevented by always using tryLock on java Lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, deadlock

Deadlocks only seem possible if there is a cyclic dependency created by the possibility of one or more threads creating a loop through lockable resources.

One option is to avoid these cycles through careful static analysis or through a design pattern for acquiring locks.

However can we prevent deadlocks by using tryLock on the Lock interface?
tryLock attemps to get the lock atomically, and returns true if successful, if its already locked then it returns false so we can simply skip over the code.

```
int sharedStateA = 0;
int sharedStateB = 0;
Lock lockA = new ReentrantLock();
Lock lockB = new ReentrantLock();

// possible deadlock safe solution

// executed by thread 1
void deadLockSafeUpdateAthenB(){
    try {
        if (lockA.tryLock()){
            sharedStateA = sharedStateA + 1; 

            try {
                if (lockB.tryLock()){
                    sharedStateB = sharedStateB + 1; 
                }
            } finally {
                lockB.unlock();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        lockA.unlock();
    }
}

// executed by thread 2
void deadLockSafeUpdateBthenA(){
    try {
        if (lockB.tryLock()){
            sharedStateB = sharedStateB + 1; 

            try {
                if (lockA.tryLock()){
                    sharedStateA = sharedStateA + 1; 
                }
            } finally {
                lockA.unlock();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        lockB.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be safe as far as deadlocking, but you have to make sure the resulting behavior is correct.

Comment: Do you understand that update of state may not happen if lock is not aquired ?  I hardly imagine when such approach may be usefull

Answer (score 2):

Your code with `Lock.tryLock()`  is deadlock safe but you should try to use the other method,

```
public boolean tryLock(long timeout,
              TimeUnit unit)
```

if your threads have short run times. The call -  `tryLock(0,TimeUnit.SECONDS)` is better than `Lock.tryLock()` because it honors fairness policy i.e. lock waiting queue is honored while `tryLock()` doesn't honor that.

Even if a static analysis tells us that a code is deadlock prone but its not always necessary that a deadlock prone code will actually produce deadlocks since its all an unlucky timing game so your target with `tryLock()` should be to produce functionally the same program as with deadlock prone code assuming that deadlock doesn't occur.

Fixing one problem shouldn't introduce other issues and in your code it looks quite possible that at some unlucky timing, one thread might not execute at all so I suggest to use timed trylock instead of barging trylock if its mandatory for lock acquisition to be in that order.

Hope it helps !!